# Symfony 'trans' domain inside Twig template

Tags: symfony, localization, twig, gettext

I'd like to do this:

```
$this->get('translator')->trans('notice.unregistered', array(), 'index');
```

Inside Twig template, so I don't have to pass this as an argument. How?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The solution is:

```
{% trans from "domain" %}text{% endtrans %}
```

Comment: how would you do it with trans filter using pipe , instead of block?

Answer (score 71):

You can also do using trans filter :

```
{{ 'translationkey'|trans({},'domain') }}
```

Comment: it don't work when you re using it to translate strings from variables.

Comment: Max you must be doing something wrong. This works for variables too (see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#twig-templates e.g. `{{ message|trans({'%name%': 'Fabien'}, "app") }}`).

Comment: well it's purpose is to work with variables, for string constants ``{% trans %}The value{% endtrans %}`` would be the way to go.

Comment: For concatenated expressions you'll have to set it up before the trans modifier:

`{% set salutation = 'salutation.' ~ person.gender %} 
{{ salutation | trans({}, 'domain') }}`

A direct `{{ 'salutation.' ~ person.gender | trans({}, 'domain') }}` doesn't work.

Comment: This does NOT work for standalone Twig -- only for Symfony Twig.

Comment: if you do not want to pass an empty array :

`{{ 'translation_key'|trans(domain='foo') }}`

Answer (score 5):

You can add custom functions to change domains inside your templates.

Add your functions:

```
$getTextdomain = new Twig_SimpleFunction('get_textdomain', function () {
    return textdomain(NULL);
});
$setTextdomain = new Twig_SimpleFunction('set_textdomain', function ($domain) {
    textdomain($domain);
});

$twig->addFunction($getTextdomain);
$twig->addFunction($setTextdomain);
```

Then use it:

```
{% set originalDomain = get_textdomain() %}
{{ set_textdomain('errors') }}
{% trans "My error message" %}
{{ set_textdomain(originalDomain) }}
```